# Selecting entire row with certain criteria, error

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following macro which is supposed to search through Col D, select rows that contain my letter 'b'.

To make things clearer for example, I want to select the entire row where 'stack' occurs in column A.

```
Sub SelectRowsb() 
    Dim z As Range 
    Dim rngb As Range 
    For Each z In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Columns("D")) 
        If z = "b" Then 
            If rngb Is Nothing Then Set rngb = z.EntireRow 
            Set rngb = Union(rngb, z.EntireRow) 
        End If 
    Next z 
    rngb.Select 
End Sub
```

I get run time error '13' type mismatch. on the if z = "b" Then

Any tips to get around this would be appreciated.

**EDIT~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~modified code so far**

```
Sub selectRowsB()
Dim varRange As String
Dim varRow As Long
varRange = ""
For varRow = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A" & varRow).Value = "stack" Then
        If varRange = "" Then
            varRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A" & varRow).EntireRow.Address
        Else
            varRange = varRange & "," & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A" & varRow).EntireRow.Address
        End If
    End If
Next
If varRange <> "" Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Range(varRange).Select
End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~modified code v2**

```
Sub test()

Dim varRange As String
Dim varRow As Long

varRange = ""

For varRow = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row

If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & varRow).Value = "insert_job" Then

    If varRange = "" Then

        varRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & varRow).EntireRow.Address

    Else

        varRange = varRange & "," & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & varRow).EntireRow.Address

    End If

End If

Next

If varRange <> "" Then

   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(varRange).Select

End If
   End Sub
```

Comment: Okay so what should I change it to? Sorry I got the code from the internet , new to this.

Comment: Sigh. You deleted the post I downvoted this morning and did some googling to arrive at this which you seem to have little understanding of :/ I guess you merely added `If z = "b" Then` and hoped it would work? Please study the code.

Comment: When you say `contain` do you mean, "b" is the only letter in the cell or is it part of a longer string?

Comment: @ScottCraner , 'b' is the only letter. I should have specified I want the exact string to be searched for.

Comment: Because below you eluded to the fact that you want when Column D = Column B. `I am looking for 'b' or whatever the value is in column B`.  So I am confused, is it the letter "b" in column D or when Column D = Column B?

Comment: Sorry. the letter 'b' is in column D. But if you want to make it easier , I want to search for 'stack' in Col A. Every occurance of 'stack' should select the entire row.

Comment: Your original code does not throw any error for me.  Not sure why yours is.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test()

Dim varRange As String
Dim varRow As Long

varRange = ""

For varRow = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row

If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & varRow).Value = "stack" Then

    If varRange = "" Then

        varRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & varRow).EntireRow.Address

    Else

        varRange = varRange & "," & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & varRow).EntireRow.Address

    End If

End If

Next

If varRange <> "" Then

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(varRange).Select

End If

End Sub
```

Apologies, just logged on as it was bugging me, this code was tested and works fine on my machine

Comment: thanks for your reply. I get compile error: Method of data member not found. Note: I am looking for 'b' or whatever the value is in column B, my active sheet is sheet1.

Comment: I keep getting same error. very odd. I changed the value from b, I just used b as a sample. But still should'nt effect it. As for Above I completely meant im looking for 'b' in col d. Sorry. To make it easier, say i am looking for 'stack' in Column A.

Comment: Apologies, missed a sheet reference

Comment: @AragDG, Hi Aran, It has no errors but nothing happens lol. Is the result suppose to select all these rows? It doesnt select anything, ill try again.

Comment: It selects the rows in which the word "stack" appears in column A as per your recent comment

Comment: I replaced stack with my real word. , sigh, i get an error on `thisworkbook.seets("sheet1".ramge(varRange).Select` , application defined or object defined error. Oddly enough it works for the word 'stack' but not my word 'insert_job:'

Comment: thisworkbook.seets("sheet1".ramge(varRange).Select should be sheets("sheet1").range

Comment: @AramDG, how come it works for stack but not my 'insert_job:' word? Stack works perfect thanks, but why not for that word?.. It seems to be because of the ':'

Comment: Without seeing your spreadsheet I could only assume it's case sensitive or your cell contains more than just insert_job:

Comment: it seems because of the ':' . When I take the colon out it works lol.

Comment: Upon furthur testing it might be because of the range. I 'find and replace' all insert_job: with insert_job. and get that same error as before.

Comment: Do you have Sheet1 selected?

Comment: Yes I am in sheet 1 cell A1. To reiterate, it works fine if I enter in a few  of 'stack'. Just won't work for many of them it seems.

Comment: Send me your workbook, cleanse of any personal / proprietory information arandgray@gmail.com

Comment: okay ill send in about an hour. Definately something to do with the amount of them.

Comment: sent it now to your email.